# EF Core 5 scalar database function translation failing

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I am trying to generate a query using `JSON_VALUE`. I have found this [thread](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/11295) and tried their solution but I am getting the following exception:

> Invalid column name 'JSON_VALUE'

Here is my current code:

OnModelCreating

```cs
modelBuilder
    .HasDbFunction(typeof(DBFunctions).GetMethod(nameof(DBFunctions.JsonValue))
    .HasName("JSON_VALUE")
    .HasTranslation(args =>
    {
        return new SqlFunctionExpression("JSON_VALUE", args, true, new[] {false, false},
            jsonValueMethod.ReturnType, stringTypeMapping);
    });
```

DBFunctions.cs

```cs
[DbFunction("JSON_VALUE", "dbo")]
public static string JsonValue(string property, [NotParameterized] string path)
{
    throw new NotSupportedException();
}

[DbFunction("JSON_QUERY", "dbo")]
public static string JsonQuery(string property, [NotParameterized] string path)
{
    throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

And then creating a database query:

```cs
dbQuery = _dbContext.RandomDocs
                    .Where(a => a.Id.ToString().StartsWith(query.Filter) ||
                                a.FullName.StartsWith(query.Filter) ||
                                SqlFunctions.JsonValue((string)(object) a.Details, "$.RandomDocs.Details").StartsWith(query.Filter)
                          );
```

Entity configuration:

```cs
builder.HasBaseType<Docs>();

builder.Property(d => d.Details)
       .HasColumnName("Details")
       .HasJsonValueConversion();
```

It doesn't generate the query successfully. Is it because it's not supported in client evaluation? Is there a better approach? I am using EF Core 5.0 and Automapper 11.0.0

Comment: Try to remove HasJsonValueConversion and work with string property. Probably properties with conversion cannot be used in SQL generation.